# Using script in jenkins run in diffrent phase

Tags: bash, shell, go, groovy

I run the following script which works

```
 sh """
    mkdir -p /go/src/git.company/mfr/go-proj
    cp -R $WORKSPACE/* /go/src/git.company/mfr/go-proj
    cd  /go/src/git.company/mfr/go-proj
    go test -v ./...
 """
```

but when I run it like this I got erorr , why ?

```
 sh   "mkdir -p /go/src/git.company/mfr/go-proj"
 sh   "cp -R $WORKSPACE/* /go/src/git.company/mfr/go-proj"
 sh   "cd  /go/src/git.company/mfr/go-proj"
 sh   "go test -v ./..."
```

any idea why ?

The file starts with `#!/usr/bin/env groovy`

Comment: And what is the error you get?

Answer (score 1):

Each "sh" is unique invocation.  Environment is not shared.

Following will run under ***two*** different shells.  change of directory will not be reflected to "go test" line

```
 sh   "cd  /go/src/git.company/mfr/go-proj"
 sh   "go test -v ./..."
```

Comment: ahh,so this is the problem , you mean that if I run it in `""` it will save the context ? it should be like `&&` command ?

Comment: each sh becomes a fresh script . For commands that are related using triple quote is fine.

Comment: There is other option except triple quote?

Comment: What is wrong with triple quotes ?  You may write your logic in any language and then call from sh.